# Can't play this video [Using VideoView/MediaPlayer + ViewPager]

Tags: java, android, video, media-player, android-mediaplayer

I'm having a problem when trying to play videos inside a ViewPager.

The problem seems pretty specific and I don't get what can be the problem.

I simplified my code to a very simple app that have a ViewPager and plays a video in each page (The videos are in the SDCard and the app have the proper permissions). And a button to move to the next and the previous page.

My **ViewPagerAdapter** is:

```
 new PagerAdapter() {
        @Override
        public int getCount() {
            return 7;
        }

        @Override
        public boolean isViewFromObject(View view, Object object) {
            return view==object;
        }

        @Override
        public int getItemPosition(Object object) {
            return POSITION_NONE;
        }

        @Override
        public Object instantiateItem(ViewGroup container, final int position) {
            View result= LayoutInflater.from(container.getContext()).inflate(R.layout.page,container,false);              
            container.addView(result);
            VideoView videoView= (VideoView) result.findViewById(R.id.videoview);
            videoView.setOnPreparedListener(new MediaPlayer.OnPreparedListener() {
                @Override
                public void onPrepared(MediaPlayer mp) {
                    mp.start();
                }
            });
            File file=new File("/sdcard/Vids/cat"+(position+1)+".webm");
            videoView.setVideoURI(Uri.fromFile(file));
            return result;
        }
        @Override
        public void destroyItem(ViewGroup container, int position, Object object) {
            View view = (View) object;
            container.removeView(view);
        }
    }
```

The buttons:

```
    view.findViewById(R.id.button_prev).setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            viewPager.setCurrentItem(viewPager.getCurrentItem()-1,true);
        }
    });
    view.findViewById(R.id.button_next).setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            viewPager.setCurrentItem(viewPager.getCurrentItem()+1,true);
        }
    }
```

The layout of each page is simple:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:orientation="vertical">
    <VideoView
        android:id="@+id/videoview"
        android:layout_margin="10dp"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent" />

</LinearLayout>
```

When you start playing arround with the next/previous buttons the problem appears:

- The main thread gets blocked for about 1-2 seconds
- A dialog appears saying "Can't play this video"
- Several errors appear in the logcat:

The logcat ouput is:

```
E/MediaPlayer: error (1, -2147479543)
E/MediaPlayer: error (1, -2147479543)
E/MediaPlayer: error (1, -38)
E/MediaPlayer: error (1, -38)
E/MediaPlayer: error (1, -2147479551)
E/MediaPlayer: error (1, -38)
E/MediaPlayer: error (1, -2147479543)
I/Choreographer: Skipped 182 frames!  The application may be doing too much work on its main thread.
E/MediaPlayer: Error (1,-2147479543)
D/VideoView: Error: 1,-2147479543
E/MediaPlayer: Error (1,-2147479543)
D/VideoView: Error: 1,-2147479543
E/MediaPlayer: Error (1,-38)
D/VideoView: Error: 1,-38
E/MediaPlayer: Error (1,-38)
D/VideoView: Error: 1,-38
E/MediaPlayer: Error (1,-2147479551)
D/VideoView: Error: 1,-2147479551
E/MediaPlayer: Error (1,-38)
```

I explored different combinations and those are my leads:

- Tried several devices (Galaxy 1, HTC One M7, Moto G2, Nexus 9, Nexus 6). It only appears in the Nexus 6.
- It happens with any video in webm format. Converting the video to solves the problem mp4
- Tried with different videos in webm format too (the problem stills there)
- I know I can add an error listener to the VideoView to remove the dialog with the error but the UI block is critical for me too.
- The error never appear in the first page, but then it seems random.

Someone knows what is going on here and how can I solve it?